# Installing 32 bit java now that ia32-sun-java6-bin is not available

Tags: java, 32-bit, multiarch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java 6/7 JRE or JDK?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-6-7-jre-or-jdk)

Prior to 11.10, I could install a 32 bit java side by side with the 64 bit versions using the package ia32-sun-java6-bin. It would install it in /usr/lib/jvm/ia32-java-6-sun and I could reference that directory when needing a 32 bit java.

But it seems that this package [was deleted in Oneiric Ocelot](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/amd64/ia32-sun-java6-bin/6.26-1oneiric1). So I was wondering whether there's a new package taking its place (maybe something having to do with multiarch?) or whether I just need to get it from sun.com or oracle.com manually.