# Problem installing Java

Tags: 11.10, java

I have not used the Ubuntu software center or the apt-get for java installation. Learning from a Ubuntu discussion thread that a manual download and install would give me the capability to place java anywhere, I've downloaded the Sun jdk bin package and executed the ./package in the Downloads folder. I see that the jre1.6_0 is installed in the Downloads directory itself. Now I am stuck. Where should the jre folder typically be? usr/bin is it?? Is it okay if I just cut and paste the installed jre folder to the specified location? So where should the folder typically reside and how to set the path? PLease help

Comment: Try installing `openjdk-6-jre` instead of Oracle Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct place for jre1.6_0 is `/usr/lib/jvm`.

Please see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69257/installing-32-bit-java-now-that-ia32-sun-java6-bin-is-not-available/69266#69266) question where I detailed manual installation steps for installing 1.7. You should easily adapt that to your case.